# How to insert an Image or Object into a special page in a Microsoft Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I want to insert a big organization chart into a separate page (the only thing I want on the page is the organization chart). I want to talk about the organization chart in the previous page of the document but I don't want to make an abrupt page break after, I mean, I want to keep writing on the page, the next page will only show the organization chart, and the next one will continue the text from the first page.

Something like this:

Page 1:

Title 1:
And we can see in the picture ... bla bla....

Title 2: Bla bla bla ..

Title n: Bla bla (reach end of page, no abrupt Page Break)

Page 2:

The image.

Page 3:

Continues the text of page 1.

Is it possible doing this on Microsoft Word ? I can't find the way.

Comment: Why would a page break not work for this? It wont insert a blank page or anything it will just stop content from continuing on that page. Would ensure that the org chart is on its own page.

Comment: Say that the paragraph that makes references ocupies only 1/4 of the page, the page break would jump to the next page, where the image would be; but 3/4 of the previous page would be empty.

Comment: Here is where i am lost then: _I want to keep writing on the page, the next page will only show the organization chart_. For that separation to happen there would be a large chunk of white space between the text and the chart if you wanted the chart on its own page. You can still add text to the page if the page break is there. The break will ensure that the picture is on its own page.

Comment: Personally, I would create the text, then place the picture manually, pronbably between two page breaks. But if you want to do the layout first, create a text box that fills page 1, then insert a page break. Insert the picture, then a page break. Then create a text box that fills page 3. Link the two text boxes. Type text into the first one and when it reaches the bottom of page 1 it will flow over to page 3. All you then need to do is resize the page 3 one if it ends up being too large. Complicated, IMO.